# Linux ARP source address wrong, when pinging from different interface

Tags: linux, networking, ping, arp

I'm seeing some weird behavior, and was hoping someone could explain to me why this is happening:

I have a linux box with two physical interfaces:

```
arnout@arnout-VirtualBox ~ $ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:46:ee:f0  
          inet addr:10.0.20.58  Bcast:10.0.23.255  Mask:255.255.252.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe46:eef0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:5942438 errors:0 dropped:1 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2012142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3291019944 (3.2 GB)  TX bytes:343769813 (343.7 MB)
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:64:eb:76  
          inet addr:1.1.1.1  Bcast:1.1.1.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe64:eb76/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:651 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:169802 (169.8 KB)
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:1107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1107 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:92180 (92.1 KB)  TX bytes:92180 (92.1 KB)

arnout@arnout-VirtualBox ~ $ uname -a
Linux arnout-VirtualBox 3.5.0-17-generic #28-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 9 19:32:08 UTC 2012 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux
```

If I ping 1.1.1.2, not having this address in the ARP cache (since it does not exist), I can see a normal ARP packet:

> "Who has 1.1.1.2, Tell 1.1.1.1"

However, when I ping using the source address of the eth0 (ping 1.1.1.1 -I 10.0.20.58), this IP actually gets put into the ARP request IP!

> "Who has 1.1.1.2, Tell **10.0.20.58**"

To me, this does not make sense at all. 
Also, host 1.1.1.2 (if it were to exist) could learn that 10.0.20.58 has the MAC address of 1.1.1.1, which is wrong. (probably not too much bad will happen)

If anybody knows why Linux is doing this, please share:)

Comment: Well, what did you expect?  More to the point, why did you use the `-I` option to set a source address that’s inappropriate for the query?

Comment: Also, I had to read the middle part of the question twice to figure out that, when you said “the second interface,” you meant `eth0`.

Comment: -I does not make it inappropriate for the query. You can ping from ANY source address. It's in the lower layer, that the problem occurs. I expect it send out "Tell 1.1.1.1", regardless of the source IP of the upper layer.

Comment: @Arnout long shot, but did you ever figure this out? I wanted to understand why Linux does this, but I have different thoughts: you're running `ping 1.1.1.1 -I 10.0.20.58` and you said `I expect it send out "Tell 1.1.1.1"` in your last comment. But I'd actually expect it to send the ping request directly to `eth0`'s default gateway, right?

Comment: @Ali, an ARP request is a broadcast, so it is sent to everyone, including the default gateway. And I do mean "Tell 1.1.1.1", since that is the IP address reachable on that interface. (+ I did not figure this out yet why linux does this though)